# Code outside functions

Tags: c++

I have written this code outside all functions:

```
int l, k;
for (l = 1; l <= node; l++)
{
    for (k = 1; k <= node; k++)
    {
        flow[i][j] = capacity[i][j];
        flow[j][i] = 0;
     }
}
```

It is giving me the following error on compilation:

```
shalini@shalini-desktop:~$ g++ -o output fords.cpp
fords.cpp:63: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘for’
fords.cpp:63: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<=’ token
fords.cpp:63: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘++’ tok
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code? if thats not in a main loop, or some other function it wont know what to do with it.

Comment: Outside all functions? It needs to be in something, otherwise it will get lost and lonely and you'll get errors.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't write code outside of functions.  The only things you can have outside of functions are declarations such as global variable declarations (usually a bad idea), function declarations etc.  Try putting it in a function like `int main(){}`

Comment: As Eric J. noted, you can declare macros outside of functions.

Comment: As a newbie to c++, coming from python, can you explain why c++ doesn't allow code outside of a function? It seems like this would be useful to do some initialization before main() is called or other funtions are even declared. (I'm not trying to argue with the compiler, I'd just like to know the thought process behind implementing it this way.)

Comment: @joshua.thomas.bird I'm happy to do so, but its a long answer, so it would be more appropriate in a new question.  Tag me in it and I'll take a shot at answering it.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to tag a person in a question, but I did make a new post, Its here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331859/why-must-c-code-be-contained-within-functions).

Comment: @joshua.thomas.bird To tag someone in a post, just make a comment with "@username"

Comment: Just curious, you mentioned you can have only declarations outside functions, but can't I say for example
static int badVar = 5;
in a header file, outside any function. I know this should not be done, but just to give an example, isn't this a definition, declaration and initialization?

Answer (score 1):

Functions organize code so that the instruction pointer can reach the code and execute it.

If the compiler would allow you to write code outside of any function it would never run.

Put the code in a function body.

C++ does allow one case where the code itself is written outside the function body, which is a macro declaration, but the [macro](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/) must be used in a function body to ever run.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring a global class variable you can execute code before the execution of main(). Put the code in the class constructor.