# Unknow type FNTYPE on function pointers

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef void (*fn)(void) FNTYPE;
FNTYPE fn_arr[5];

void fun1(void){
        printf("\n I'm func 1 \n");
}

void fun2(void){
        printf("\n I'm func 2 \n");
}


fn_arr[0] = &fun1;
fn_arr[1] = &fun2;

int decidefunc(char* inp){
        if(inp == NULL){
                return 0;
        }
        else if(*inp == "a"){
                return 1;
        }
        else if(*inp == "b"){
                return 0;
        }
        else if(*inp == "c"){
                return 1;
        }
        else{
                return 0;
        }
}

void callMyFunc(char* inp){
        printf("\n %s \n",__func__);
        int idx = decidefunc(inp);
        fn_arr[idx]();
}

void do_lengthy_op(char* inp,void (*call)(char *inp)){
        printf("\n do_lengthy_operation! \n");
        call(inp);
}

int main(){
        do_lengthy_op("b",callMyFunc);
        return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the above error for the simple c programs on callback. Couldn't find why the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work after fixing the following issues.

1. To define a `pointer-to-function` type, you need to use the following instead:

   ```
   typedef void (*FNTYPE)(void);
   ```
2. To correctly compare `char`, you need to change

   ```
   else if(*inp == "a"){
       return 1;
   }
   else if(*inp == "b"){
       return 0;
   }
   else if(*inp == "c"){
       return 1;
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   else if(*inp == 'a'){
       return 1;
   }
   else if(*inp == 'b'){
       return 0;
   }
   else if(*inp == 'c'){
       return 1;
   }
   ```
3. Move the following into `main()` as you can NOT have [Code outside functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313450/code-outside-functions).

   ```
   fn_arr[0] = &fun1;
   fn_arr[1] = &fun2;
   ```

See it live: http://ideone.com/vbandN.

Answer (score 2):

1. Typedef statement looks just like variable declaration, prefixed by `typedef`. The name of the type is in the same place where the name of the variable will be, so it should be `typedef void (*FNTYPE)(void) ;` not `typedef void (*fn)(void) FNTYPE;`
2. You cannot perform assignment to array outside a function, either do it in a function or in the array initialisation.

   ```
   fn_arr[0] = &fun1;
   fn_arr[1] = &fun2;
   ```