# Array pointer outside of main function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, compilation, declaration

Here is another total-beginner-noob question of me: when putting the lines

```
double w[1];
double *l;
l = w;
```

into the `main()` function, everything works perfectly well when compiling, however, when putting it before the `main()` (as declared variables), then the error

> expected '`,`' or '`;`' before '`=`' token

appears for the last line.

Also, putting the former two before `main()` and only `l = w;` into the `main()` will work fine. Why is that so? Does it have something to do with compile/runtime? Can I not assign values outside `main()` when having them declared before? If so, why?

Comment: As You already noted You can't have expressions outside of functions. As to why... think when those expressions should be evaluated - and assume multiple compilation units which could reference same variables.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313450/code-outside-functions

Comment: @rAndom69 well you can write `int dummy = ((l = w), 0);`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean...one can define global variables outside functions. Also, what works is something like "int r = 4; int t = r;" however, what does not work is "int r = 4; int t; t = r;" so the question is: What is the difference with those two things?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have freestanding expressions outside of functions in C++.

You can work around this by moving the expression to the initializer of `l`:

```
double w[1];
double *l = w;
```

Answer (score 0):

For why it works, declarations can be made outside a function - however, by doing so, you are declaring it as a global variable.

C++ can initialize a variable after you declare it, however, it will not run anything else other than that. So in this case, the expression

```
l = w;
```

will not run because it is not inside a method.