# Asking the user if they want to run a program again in C

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, printf, do-while

I'm new to coding so please forgive me if this is a stupid question. I am trying to create a program in C where the user can input the number of a month and then they are told how many days are in that month. My code works in a console, until I try to implement a way where the user is asked to begin the program again.

This is what I have tried to use so far in order to get it to work, but I cannot wrap my head around why it isn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Errors I received were:
main.c: In function ‘function’:

main.c:6:1: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘do’
do
^~

main.c:42:2: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘while’
}while(1);
^~~~~

main.c:42:2: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input

```
#include <stdio.h>

char choice;
do
{
    void printDays(int D) 
    { 
        if (D == 2) { 
            printf("This month has 28 days"); 
        } 

        else if (D == 4 || D == 6 
                || D == 9 || D == 11) { 
            printf("This month has 30 days"); 
        } 

        else if (D == 1 || D == 3 || D == 5 
            || D == 7 || D == 8 || D == 10 
            || D == 12) { 
            printf("This month has 31 days"); 
        } 
  
        else { 
            printf("Invalid month"); 
        } 
    } 

    int main() 
    { 
        int D = ; 
    
        printDays(D); 
    } 
    printf("Run the program again? (Y/N) ?"); 
    scanf("%c",&choice);
    if(choice=='n' || choice=='N') 
        break;
}while(1);
```

Comment: Orange1998NL, Posted code fails to compile.  What error messages did you get?  They are most useful in solving such issues.

Comment: @Orange1998NL I very doubt that except you yourself somebody else will want to run your program one more.:)

Comment: @Orange1998NL Use a while or do-while loop within main.

Comment: What do you mean by "code works in a console"?  The code you've presented doesn't even compile.

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put the `do while` outside all the functions. [Code outside functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313450/code-outside-functions)
The program is fine, just put the loop inside the main

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printDays(int D) 
{ 
    if (D == 2) { 
        printf("This month has 28 days"\n); 
    } 

    else if (D == 4 || D == 6 
            || D == 9 || D == 11) { 
        printf("This month has 30 days\n"); 
    } 

    else if (D == 1 || D == 3 || D == 5 
        || D == 7 || D == 8 || D == 10 
        || D == 12) { 
        printf("This month has 31 days"\n); 
    } 

    else { 
        printf("Invalid month"); 
    } 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    char choice;
    int D;
    
    do {
        if( scanf("%d", &D) != 1 ) for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar());
        printDays(D);
        printf("Run the program again? (Y/N) ?\n"); 
        scanf(" %c",&choice);

    }while( choice != 'n' && choice != 'N');
     
}
```

The condition

```
if( scanf("%d", &D) != 1 )
```

Is checking whether scanf successfully read an integer. While this loop

```
for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar());
```

Is used to discard any character left unread in case the user entered something that wasn't a number. If you don't discard those characters, then they will be read by the next scanf (the one for the `choice`) instead of the the real choice typed by the user. The real choice would stay in queue waiting that you read enough characters to get to it. Hope it was clear enough.

I suggest you to read [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) comments to this answer, about this error handling and more (leading space in `" %c"`).

Comment: Should use `scanf(" %c",&choice);` (the space consumes the `'\n'` left in stdin by `scanf("%d", &D);`) Also must check `if (scanf("%d", &D) != 1) { /* handle matching-failure */ }` which includes emptying the offending characters from `stdin`, e.g. `for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}`

Comment: Oh thanks for the leading space, I missed it. Regarding the error handling, I added it even if the OP is a beginner and possibly won't have nothing to do with that.

Comment: It just save things if there is an accident of pressing `'r'` reaching for `'4'`, etc.. Otherwise, when the matching failure occurs with `scanf("%d", &D);`, character extraction from `stdin` ceases, `"r\n"` is left unread, by happy mistake `scanf(" %c",&choice)` reads `'r'` for `choice`, etc.. The accidental saving grace is `" %c"` is there to eventually empty the characters left unread in `stdin`. What you always want to emphasize is you can't use ANY user-input function correctly unless you ***check the return***. That applies with especial vigor to every user of `scanf()`.

Comment: If you look at the original comment the character extraction applies to `if (scanf("%d", &D) != 1) { /* handle matching-failure */ }` because the `"%d"` is subject to the *matching-failure* while `"%c"` is not. `"%c"` simply reads a character -- whatever it may be. (though the character extraction is needed after each call to handle any extraneous characters entered by the user) Further, `"%d"` consumes leading whitespace, while `"%c"`, `"%[..]"`, and `"%n"` do not, which is why the whitespace in  `" %c"` is needed. All of which are reasons why you do NOT do user-input with `scanf()` `:)`

Comment: Thank you very much, I put an explanation for the error handling in the answer

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted will not compile.

Each programming language will have its own syntax and semantic rules. `C` programs also need to be written by following certain syntax and semantic rules.

Below program highlights ***very basic way*** of writing a program in `C` language.

Below in-lined comments helps you understand the different sections of program.

```
//header files first
#include <stdio.h>

//macro declarations such as #define MAX 10
//global variable declarations or definitions

//function prototypes
void printDays(int D);

//main function
int main() 
{ 
    //local variables declarations, initializations
    int D = 0;
    char choice;

    //do while(), is one of looping statements
    do 
    {
        printf("enter month number to find out number of days\n");

        //one of the ways of reading input from stdin
        scanf("%d", &D);

        //function call  
        printDays(D);

        printf("Run the program again? (Y/N) ?"); 
        scanf(" %c",&choice);
          
    }while( (choice != 'n') && (choice != 'N' ) );

    //function return value
    return 0;
} 

//function defintion
void printDays(int D) 
{ 
    //conditional statments
    if (D == 2) { 
        printf("This month has 28 days"); 
    } 
    else if (D == 4 || D == 6 || D == 9 || D == 11) { 
        printf("This month has 30 days"); 
    } 
    else if (D == 1 || D == 3 || D == 5 || D == 7 || D == 8 || D == 10 || D == 12) { 
        printf("This month has 31 days"); 
    } 
    else { 
        printf("Invalid month"); 
    } 
}
```

NOTE: As per the number of days in a given month goes, the special case for month `Feb` has to be handled ,because `Feb` has 29 days in a leap year.

Since you are saying new to programming go through some [tutorials in c](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html?inl=hp)

Comment: `while(choice != 'n' || choice != 'N' );` should be either `while(choice != 'n' && choice != 'N' );`  or  `while(choice == 'n' || choice == 'N' );`

Comment: Oh I never thought about that. It's true, I could start editing people's answers,  thanks for the idea.

Comment: Few people edited my answer for small corrections, so will get a suggestion