# How can I make these two examples from the C++ book run?

Tags: c++

I'm reading from a C++ book (C++ For Dummies) and I'm trying to learn by copying examples from this book and typing them onto an online IDE and I need help learning as to why this code will not run. Thank you. It's very stressful for me and I would love to fully learn this language one day.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   int x;
   x = 9;
   x > 10;
   
 
   
  
   char mychar;
   
   mychar = 'a';
   
   mychar == 'A';
   

   
  
   
   mychar != 'X';
   
 

   
   
   int i = 7;
   (i < 10 || i > 100);
   
   
 
  if (x > 10)
  {
      std::cout << "Yuppers, it's greater than 10!" << std::endl;
  }
 
  
   std::cout << "Type any number:  ";
   std::cin >> i;
   if (i > 10)
   {
       std::cout << "It's greater than 10." << std::endl; 
   }
   else
   {
       std::cout << "It's not greater than 10." << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
   
}



int i;
std::cout << "Type any number:  ";
std::cin >> i;

if (i > 10)
{
    std::cout << "It's greater than 10." << std::endl;
}
else if (i == 10)
{
    std::cout << "It's equal to 10" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "It's less than 10." << std::endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure why it's not running, but I think it's due to the second half of code, after the first

return 0;

of course

Comment: Can you please edit this question to remove the verbose comments and indicate which lines are causing the problem? There's a whole lot of "code" here that doesn't appear to be even potentially related to the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: It's possible that the problem here is that you can't have code that just runs freefloating outside of a function. This code includes stuff like `std::cout << "Type any number: "` outside of `main` that should cause it to refuse to compile. (If your code isn't compiling, showing the actual error message you're getting would be more helpful than just the vague "it can't run")

Comment: Sounds good. I'm new here so I may stumble around a bit. I'll go ahead and edit the post

Comment: [Your code without all of the comments](https://godbolt.org/z/GEac8ovhz)

Comment: The problem is that your main function ends at line `54` at `}`. See the comment in [this demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Bx6laA8YS)

Comment: [You can't write code outside of functions. The only things you can have outside of functions are declarations such as global variable declarations (usually a bad idea), function declarations etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11313473/12002570)

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the highly-verbose comments, you find out that the code in line 126 and afterward is written outside the `main` function. That's why the program is compiled when everything after line 126 is deleted.

They need to be contained in it before they can be called.

Currently, they are like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
  .
  .
}

int i;
std::cout << "Type any number:  ";
.
.
```

This needs to be like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
  .
  .
  int i;
  std::cout << "Type any number:  ";
  .
  .
}
```

However, `int i = 7` is previously declared. So re-declaration will result in a compilation error. As long as `i` is not a constant, you can reassign it instead.

Comment: How do I reassign it

Comment: After the first declaration, `int i = 123;`, when you wish to reuse it, you reassign it by calling it again like this: `i = 456;`

Comment: I typed in what you said on the second half of the code and I got this:   main.cpp:128:5: error: redefinition of ‘int main()’
  128 | int main(void) {
      |     ^~~~
main.cpp:6:5: note: ‘int main()’ previously defined here
    6 | int main()
      |     ^~~~

Comment: @JohnSmith It says you have defined two `int main()`. You can only have one unique `main` function in a file.

Comment: A program has a single `main` function. You don't put two `main` functions back to back. These examples are not supposed to all just be amalgamated willy-nilly into a single translation unit. You might need to pay closer attention to the text of the book and not just the code snippets themselves.

Comment: What do you think my next step should be, to fix this?

Comment: @JohnSmith Remove one of the `main` functions and let the entire code be contained in a single `main` function.