# cpp thread detach position?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

my simple test code here:

```cpp
// t.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>    
#include <thread> 

void fcn()
{
    uint8_t i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        std::cout<<"hihi" << float(i++)<<std::endl;
    }
}

std::thread t(fcn);

t.detach(); // detach position A

int main()
{
    // t.detach(); // detach position B
    
    uint8_t i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        std::cout<<"yoyo" << float(i++)<<std::endl;
    }

}
```

compile and run by `g++ ./t.cpp -o t -lpthread; ./t`;

when detach at `position A` got compile error `error: ‘t’ does not name a type | t.detach();`,
but detach at `position B` is ok.

why is this different?

my situation is that i wish to move the `fcn()` and `std::thread t(fcn)` as well as `t.detach()` into a standalone header file later (for a better orginazation of the project) thanks

Comment: Code like `t.detach();` is not allowed outside a function.

Comment: thanks very much, may i have some references docs/link for this? @RetiredNinja

Comment: any c or c++ tutorial or book will tell you that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code outside functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313450/code-outside-functions)

Comment: When do you want `t.detach()` to execute?